# How to make input readonly, but still allow some keys to work

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-5

I have one input box. I am showing some value in it. I want to make that input box as read-only. But arrows key, Home key, End key these keys should work.

I am showing multiple URLs by comma separated way. I want to navigate between these URLs. That's why I need above keys should work.

I tried with `[readonly]="true"`, but I cant navigate within input box.
I can not use `disabled` as well.

```
<input matInput placeholder="Enter Promotional Link URL"  [(ngModel)]="lms.LmPromotionalUrl" name="LmPromotionalUrl">
```

output

```
www.facebook.com,www.google.com,www.cisco.com
```

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: May I specify something? 
As I understood your input is too small to show the whole content of it ?
Probably if that is the problem, you may just forbid all keys using JS and allow just those you mentioned

Comment: @Sh.Pavel I had tried `keyup` and `keydown` events as well. It works when the input box is empty. But when data is present then this is not working.

Comment: hmm..it's wierd..maybe the good point would be to add some check on the content length ? Like if there is length > 0 then would be check on the keyup/keydown events? But i'm not sure if this would work.. I had never applied it to disabled input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in plain javascript, you can simply adapt that to a HostListener or `(keydown)` in angular. Basically we're just returning false and preventing default behavior for any key that is not the arrow keys (I'm using a mac and don't know which home key is, you can check that [here](http://keycode.info/) and add it to the array of allowed keycodes

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (![37, 38, 39, 40].includes(e.keyCode)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

})
```

```html
<input id="foo" placeholder="Enter Promotional Link URL" name="LmPromotionalUrl" value="foo">
```

In the example you can still "navigate" through the values using arrow keys, but can't type or delete anything.

Comment: my value `(lms.LmPromotionalUrl)` is an array of URLs. when I am trying to push new URL into that array. It giving me an error. Because array getting converted into the string.

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question if you have a different one @KaustubhKhare

Comment: I did changes as you suggested, but when I am passing data to `value`, it is converting the array into the string and I am getting the error while adding new URL for `unshift` method.

Comment: Like written in the answer, you need to adapt the code to angular. You'd set the data just like you did before, not with value @KaustubhKhare

Comment: I tried. It works when the input box is empty. But when data is present then this is not working.

Comment: If you update your question with your current code I'll have a look @KaustubhKhare